# Android Studio - 2 Spinners In One Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Firstly, i am a novice at android and java. Just learning, and i need a little help. Now this is how this activity is supposed to work.

There are two spinners. Spinner A - Spinner B

Spinner A contains a list of "Majors" (e.g, I.T, Medicine, Vet)

Spinner B contains a list of Programs, which are under each "Major". So under I.T there are things link MIS, or DATABASE etc.

Now, Spinner B has to change based on Spinner A. So If Spinner A has I.T Selected, then Spinner B should show only I.T Programs. If the person changes their selection on Spinner A to Medicine, then Spinner B has to immediately change and show ONLY Medicine programs.

Now i've gotten all of this to work. BUT, the problem i am having is that i cannot get the onItemSelectedListerner to work (i.e, it is only listening for selections from Spinner A, but any selections from spinner B are ignored).

I tested this by setting a Toast on All of Spinner B's selections, so when ever you select something in spinner B, you should get a toast, but that doesnt happen.

So Spinner A , the Listener is working fine for, but it is not listening to spinner B. Help Please?

Also, the reason i need a "response" or "action" from Spinner B is because, based on Spinner B's selection, it will display different data in the following Activity. (which will be a list view)

```
package com.example.chadedwards.sgu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ActivityTwo extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

String str_student_id, str_semester, str_year, str_studentName, str_studentAddress, str_studentMajor, str_studentProgram;
EditText  student_name, student_address;
Button int2_submit;
Spinner student_major,student_program, it_programs, hss_programs, bms_programs, bec_programs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_two);

    //Retrieve passed data from main activity in BundleA
    final Bundle bundleA = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    str_student_id = bundleA.getString("studentid");
    str_year = bundleA.getString("year");
    str_semester = bundleA.getString("semester");
    //Set the textview at the top of the layout to the ID retrieved from main_activity
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_studentID)).setText("Student ID: " + str_student_id);


    student_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    student_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_address);
    int2_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.int2_submit);


    student_major = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_major);
    ArrayAdapter majorAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.major_names, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    student_major.setAdapter(majorAdapter);

    student_program = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_program);

    student_major.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
    student_program.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);




    // Action Performed When Submit Button Is Clicked
    int2_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            str_studentName = student_name.getText().toString();
            str_studentAddress = student_address.getText().toString();
            //str_studentMajor = student_major.getText().toString();
            //str_studentProgram = student_program.getText().toString();

            //Create new intent along with bundle data to pass
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityThree.class);
            Bundle bundleB = new Bundle();
            //add data to bundle
           /* bundleB.putString("studentid", str_student_id);
            bundleB.putString("semester", str_semester);
            bundleB.putString("year", str_year);
            bundleB.putString("studentname", str_studentName); */
            bundleB.putString("studentaddress", str_studentAddress);
            // bundleB.putString("studentmajor",str_studentMajor);
            bundleB.putString("studentprogram", str_studentProgram);
            //pass bundle to intent and start the activity using the intent
            myIntent2.putExtras(bundleB);
            myIntent2.putExtras(bundleA);
            ActivityTwo.this.startActivity(myIntent2);

        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch(parent.getId()) {
        //Run Code For Major Spinner
        case R.id.spinner_major:
             switch(position){
                 case 0:

                    if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner_program){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Yay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                     ArrayAdapter hssProgramAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.hss_programs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                     student_program.setAdapter(hssProgramAdapter);

                     Toast.makeText(this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


                     switch(parent.getId()){

                         case R.id.spinner_program:

                             Toast.makeText(this, "TESTING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                             break;

                     }



                     break;

                 case 1:

                     ArrayAdapter itProgramAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.it_programs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                     student_program.setAdapter(itProgramAdapter);

                     Toast.makeText(this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                     break;

                 case 2:

                     ArrayAdapter bmsProgramAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bms_programs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                     student_program.setAdapter(bmsProgramAdapter);

                     Toast.makeText(this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                     break;

                 case 3:

                     ArrayAdapter becProgramAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.bec_programs, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                     student_program.setAdapter(becProgramAdapter);


                     Toast.makeText(this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                     break;

             }//switch positions
            break;
        }//switch parents


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In OnItemSelected you need to write two cases one for first spinner and other for other spinner

```
@Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{ switch(parent.getId()) 
{ //Run Code For Major Spinner
 case R.id.spinner_major: 
{ // code for first spinner. Depending on spinner.getselecteditem assign adapter to second spinner 
}
case R.id.second_spinner:
 { // code for second spinner 
 //Use get item selected and get selected item position
    }
```